# Is there any way to uninstall DirectX 12 from Windows 10 and install DirectX 11

Tags: directx

I have Intel HD 3000 graphics which are not compatible with DirectX 12. I am having issues in some games so I thought maybe I could install DirectX 11 on Windows 10 which is compatible with my GPU. Please help me if you know how to solve this issue/

Comment: Hi, and welcome. This isn't the right place for this question. StackOverflow is for questions about programming and algorithms. The appropriate place for this question is [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to and you shouldn't, too.

DirectX 11 and DirectX 12 are two different APIs, they are not compatible with each other. What DirectX version that the game will be using has been decided when the game was made. It means you can't "upgrade" or "downgrade" DirectX by installing different drivers or by any other configurations.